# scrapy python pass start_urls from spider to pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to pass the **start_urls** from my spider to the Mysqlpipeline.

how can I do that?

This is part of my **spider.py**

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    urls = kwargs.pop('urls', [])
    if urls:
        self.start_urls = urls.split(',')
    self.logger.info(self.start_urls)
    url = "".join(urls)
    self.allowed_domains = [url.split('/')[-1]]
    super(SeekerSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

and this is my **pipeline.py**

```
class MySQLPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):

        ...

        #  get the url from the spiders
        start_url = SeekerSpider.start_urls  # not working    

        url = "".join(start_url).split('/')[-1]
        self.tablename = url.split('.')[0]
```

***UPDATE***

This is another way I tried but if I have 100 requests...it will create the table 100 times...

**pipeline.py**

```
class MySQLPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
       ...

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
       tbl_name = item['tbl_name']
        general_table = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CrawledTables
                            (id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                            Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                            Date VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                            PRIMARY KEY (id), UNIQUE KEY (NAME))
                            ENGINE=Innodb DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 """

        insert_table = """ INSERT INTO CrawledTables (Name,Date) VALUES(%s,%s)"""

        self.cursor.execute(general_table)
        crawled_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y/%m/%d-%H:%M")
        self.cursor.execute(insert_table, (tbl_name,
                                           str(crawled_date)))

        ...
```

**spider.py**

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    urls = kwargs.pop('urls', [])
    if urls:
        self.start_urls = urls.split(',')
    self.logger.info(self.start_urls)
    url = "".join(urls)
    self.allowed_domains = [url.split('/')[-1]]
    super(SeekerSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y_%m_%d_%H_%M")
    self.dmn = "".join(self.allowed_domains).replace(".", "_")

    tablename = urls.split('/')[-1]
    table_name = tablename.split('.')[0]
    newname = table_name[:1].upper() + table_name[1:]
    date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y_%m_%d_%H_%M")
    self.tbl_name = newname + "_" + date

def parse_page(self, response):

    item = CrawlerItem()
    item['tbl_name'] = self.tbl_name

    ...
```

In this table I am trying to add only 1 time the table that I'm crawling with the date...basically I'm taking the **start_urls** and pass it to the **allowed_domain** and then pass it to the **tbl_name** (for the mysql table name)

Comment: You can't do that in your init. but in your `process_item`. Because pipelines are initialized before the process

Comment: it works in the **process_item** but it calls it every request...so if i have 100 requests...it will try to create that table 100 times...and i only want 1 time

Comment: I have Update the question

Answer (score 4):

I found out that i need to create another function in the **pipeline**

```
def open_spider(self, spider):
```

and this takes all the arguments that you have in your spider and you use them in the pipeline